# Classifier Loss function dimension out of range error

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

```
import torch.nn as nn

class MyModel(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()

        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 32, kernel_size=5, stride=2, padding=2)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=5,stride=2)

        self.fc = nn.Linear(884736, 1000)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(1000, 600)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(600, 200)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(200, 6)

        self.pooling = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)



    def forward(self, x):

        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = nn.functional.relu(x)
        x= self.pooling(x)

        x= self.conv2(x)

        x = torch.flatten(nn.functional.relu(x))

        x= self.fc(x)
        x = nn.functional.relu(x)
        # import pdb; pdb.set_trace()

        x= self.fc1(x)
        x= self.fc2(x)
        x= self.fc3(x)

        # x = torch.softmax(x)



        return x

# model = torch.nn.Sequential(
# )

model = MyModel()

#Training

dataiter = iter(trainloader)
total_epochs = 5
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters())

for epoch in tqdm(range(total_epochs)):

  #initialize batch
  gc.collect()
  input_, label_ = dataiter.next()

  #forwardd
  out = model.forward(input_)

  #backwardd     
  print (out,out.shape,)

  print (label_, label_.shape)
  # out = out.unsqueeze(dim=0)

  # label_ =label_.type_as(out)
  loss = criterion(out, label_)
  loss.backward()

  optimizer.zero_grad()
  optimizer.step()

  print('batch_loss:', str(loss.item()))

  print('Epochs completed:', epoch+1,'\n')
  print('epoch_loss:' + loop_loss/float(batch_size))
```

I have a dataset of different breed of dogs (120 classes)
http://vision.stanford.edu/aditya86/ImageNetDogs/images.tar

The labels are int values ranging from 1 to 120

I need to make a classifier

Getting an error at loss computation
Dimension out of range (expected to be in range of [-1, 0], but got 1)

What could be wrong?

Comment: Put all the error log first.

Answer (score 0):

The output of the model has only a single dimension, it has the size *[6]*, but the [`nn.CrossEntropyLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss) expects a size of *[batch_size, num_classes]*.

In the model you flatten the output of the convolutions. You have to preserve the batch dimension, as they are independent of each other and flattening it completely would combine them into a single one. [`torch.flatten`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.flatten) accepts a `start_dim` argument (second argument), which decides from which dimension it starts to flatten. By setting it to 1, it will start with the second dimension, leaving the first dimension (batch dimension) unchanged.

```py
# Flatten everything but the first dimension
# From: [batch_size, channels, height, width] (4D)
# To: [batch_size, channels * height * width] (2D)
x = torch.flatten(nn.functional.relu(x), 1)
```

The output of the model must also have the same number of classes as your dataset. Since you have 120 classes, the output of the last linear layer must be 120.

```py
self.fc3 = nn.Linear(200, 120)
```

Also, the labels need to be in range *[0, 119]*, because they are the indices of the classes and like every indexing in Python, it is zero-based. If your labels are in range *[1, 120]*, you can simply subtract one from them.